# Changing idle timeout in Spring Boot shell

Tags: spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot 1.2.7 remote shell (CRaSH 1.3.2) and cannot seem to change the idle timeout from the default 10 minutes. In my application.properties I have

> shell.ssh.port=2111
>
> shell.ssh.idle_timeout=7200000

On startup, the properties while seems to be read successfully, the port is set to the desired value, but the timeout remains the default 10 minutes (600 000 msec):

> o.s.b.a.a.CrshAutoConfiguration$CrshBootstrapBean - Configuring property ssh.port=2111 from properties
>
> o.s.b.a.a.CrshAutoConfiguration$CrshBootstrapBean - Configuring property ssh.auth_timeout=600000 from properties
>
> o.s.b.a.a.CrshAutoConfiguration$CrshBootstrapBean - Configuring property ssh.idle_timeout=600000 from properties

Apparently the shell.ssh.idle_timeout property (originally crash.ssh.idle_timeout in CRaSH, which I also tried along with other names) is not exposed by Spring Boot. I couldn't find any information on other ways to set it. Is there a way to set it e.g. from a configuration class?

**EDIT:** I was pulled off the project, so I didn't get to solve it, I only have some pointers to those with the same problem. These properties are read by org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.ShellProperties which I was going to extend with the idle timeout property and then try and inject into CrshAutoConfiguration in the same package. There may of course be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

There was [a request to support this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4325) and this has been fixed in Spring Boot 1.3.0.RELEASE (about to be released at the time of writing)